# iptables packet forwarding - keep client IP

Tags: iptables, forwarding, ubuntu-16.04

I have similar problem to this: [Keep source IP after NAT](https://serverfault.com/questions/452183/keep-source-ip-after-nat)

I need to forward packets on a specific port from ip x.x.x.x to y.y.y.y. (x.x.x.x server is located in a different country outside x.x.x.x server LAN)
I used rules mentioned in the question above but client packets still seem to arrive from forward server IP x.x.x.x and not from client IP.

Here are rules i use + ufw firewall with SSH port opened and forwarding allowed:

```
FORWARDER_IP=x.x.x.x &&
SERVER_IP=y.y.y.y &&
SERVICE_PORT=12345 &&
TRANSPORT=udp &&

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p $TRANSPORT -d $FORWARDER_IP --dport $PORT -j DNAT --to $SERVER_IP &&
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p $TRANSPORT -d $SERVER_IP --dport $PORT -j SNAT --to $FORWARDER_IP &&
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p $TRANSPORT -s $SERVER_IP --dport $PORT -j SNAT --to $FORWARDER_IP
```

Any idea what could be my problem?

Is this even possible? If not, could you recommend me another way to do this?

Comment: You're doing `-j SNAT`  ( source NAT) which replaces the original source ip-address, which you shouldn't be using if you don't want to replace the original client ip-address

Comment: If I don't use SNAT packets are dropped because reply comes from y.y.y.y not from x.x.x.x. There is no active connection between client and y.y.y.y.